# How to prove the following function is a zero function: $f(x)=a_1|x-1| + ...+ a_n|x-n|$ under condition all $f(i) = 0$ where $i \in [1. 2.... n]$.

Tags: functions, contest-math

How to prove the following function is a zero function: $f(x)=a_1|x-1| + a_2|x-1| + ...+ a_n|x-n|$ under the condition that all $f(i) = 0$ where $i \in [1. 2.... n]$.

It seems an induction problem but although n = 2 is obvious, the induction relation is a little bit hard to find.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2079932/399263

Comment: Surely $f(x) = |x-1|$ satisfies $f(1) = 0$ (with $n=1$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $a_j\neq 0$, notice $f'(j+\frac{1}{2}) = f'(j-\frac{1}{2}) + 2a_j$.

It follows that the derivative is not zero for one of those values. Suppose without loss of generality that $f'(j+\frac{1}{2}) = m \neq 0$.

We have $f(j+1) = f(j) + m$ and so one of those two is not $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x \mapsto |x-k|$ is affine on $(-\infty,k]$ and $[k,\infty)$ and so $f$ is affine on $(\infty,1]$, $[1,2]$,$...$,$[n-1,n]$,$ [n,\infty)$.

Since $f(k) = 0$ for $k=1,...,n$ we see that $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [1,n]$.

Suppose $n \ge 2$.

Note that for $h \in (0,1)$ and $k \in \{1,...,n\}$ we have $f(k+h)-f(k-h) = 2a_k h$ and
so $a_k = 0$ for $k \in \{2,...,n-1\}$.

Hence for $x \in [1,n]$ we have $f(x) = a_1 (x-1)+a_n(n-x) = 0$ and so $a_1=a_n$ and $n a_n = a_1$ hence $a_1 = a_n = 0$.